# How to call Turtle window from a GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

I'm trying to open a Turtle window from a GUI to select a position on the image with a mouse click. The x and y coordinates are then returned as an input to the GUI.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkFont
import turtle

xclick = 0
yclick = 0

def callback3():
    getcoordinates()


def getcoordinates():
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.setup(400, 400)
    screen.bgpic("stunden.gif")
    screen.onscreenclick(modifyglobalvariables)

    
def modifyglobalvariables(rawx,rawy):
    global xclick
    global yclick
    xclick = int(rawx//1)
    yclick = int(rawy//1)
    print(xclick)
    print(yclick)
    turtle.bye()


root = Tk()

helv30 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=30)

button1 = Button(root, text = "1", width=3, font=helv30, borderwidth=0, command=callback3)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Then the error `image "pyimage2" doesn't exist` shows up. I found out, that it has something to do with two instances of `Tk`, as there is the root and the turtle window and that I should solve it with `Toplevel()`. However, after hours of research and try and error I still could not come up with the right solution to make my code work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note you tagged your question incorrectly, it should be "tkinter" not "tinker". Regardless, my advice is to not use `turtle` to do this. At best it will be awkward because that module uses `tkinter` its implementation — and especially in this case since you can very like do the same thing without too much difficulty directly via `tkinter` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion martineau. Could you give me a hint how to do it directly with tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to implement it directly in `tkinter` — so no `turtle` module required — as I suggested earlier in a (now-deleted) comment:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkFont

CLOCK_IMAGE_PATH = 'clock.png'
xclick, yclick = 0, 0

def callback3():
    window = Toplevel()
    window.title("Stunden")
    img = PhotoImage(file=CLOCK_IMAGE_PATH)
    img_width, img_height = img.width(), img.height()
    window.minsize(width=img_width, height=img_height)
    canvas = Canvas(window, width=img_width, height=img_height)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.image = img  # Keep reference to avoid image being garbage collected.
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=img)
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", get_coordinates)  # Set up event-handler callback.

def get_coordinates(event):
    global xclick, yclick
    xclick = int(event.x // 1)
    yclick = int(event.y // 1)
    print(f'xclick={xclick}, yclick={yclick}')

root = Tk()
helv30 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=30)
button1 = Button(root, text="1", width=3, font=helv30, borderwidth=0, command=callback3)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=0)
root.mainloop()
```